# Excel formula to extra data from oddly formatted list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a .csv with phone numbers, and I'd like to extract specific info from a column so I can import it into another program.

Basically, the data is phone numbers that are scrubbed through the DNC list -- but, the phone numbers show like this:

9995551212, 1234567890 DNC, 4432325555

So, the first and last numbers are safe to call, the middle one should be removed.

I'd like to create a new column where the clean data is stored -- it should look at each of the numbers, separated by a comma, and determine if "DNC" is the last three letters. If DNC shows, that phone # should be excluded. If it's just numbers, we should include that data.

I'm honestly at a loss as to how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are the commas in the cell value as well, and does that mean that for the example you provided, you are expecting `9995551212, 4432325555` as result?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=if(iferror(find("dnc",A1,1),0)>0,"",A1)
```

So find looks for dnc if it finds it then if puts a blank.

[image]

Edit, reading the comment, if the data is just text in one cell, then "text to columns" will extract...

Answer (score 0):

## Extract Phone Number (UDF)

Copy the following code to a standard module (In VBE: `Insert>Add Module`).

The parameters of the 2nd ("**,**") and 3rd ("**,** ") arguments are adjusted (default) for your convenience, but can be changed.

### The Code

```
Function EPN(SourceString As Variant, Optional ByVal SplitDelimiter = ",", _
        Optional ByVal JoinDelimiter = ", ") As String

    Dim strC As String    ' Current String
    Dim strT As String    ' Target String
    Dim vntS As Variant   ' String Array
    Dim i As Long         ' String Array Element Counter

    ' Split Source String to String Array.
    vntS = Split(CStr(SourceString), SplitDelimiter)
    ' Loop through elements of String Array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(vntS)
        ' Write current element of String Array to Current String.
        strC = Trim(vntS(i))
        ' Check if current string is 'recognized' as a number.
        If IsNumeric(strC) Then
            ' Check if Target String is not empty ("").
            If strT <> "" Then  ' Target String is NOT empty.
                ' Concatenate current Target String, Join Delimiter _
                ' and Current String.
                strT = strT & JoinDelimiter & strC
              Else              ' Target String IS empty (only once).
                ' Write Current String to Target String.
                strT = strC
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Write Target String to EPN (Extract Phone Number).
    EPN = strT

End Function
```

### Usage In Excel

Use e.g. `=EPN(A1)` and copy down.

```
=EPN("asdfasf, 9999,234324 ,234DNC5342,erter,E234,dsfa")
```

will result in `9999, 234324`.